# Python : Find restaurants which satisfy conditions of mean and count

Tags: python, count, average

I have a dataset with information regarding restaurants, which cuisine type clients were looking for, prices of order, ratings among other columns. All restaurants have a rating between 1 and 5 (max).Some ratings are NaN.

The company wants to provide a promotional offer in the advertisement of the restaurants. The condition to get the offer is that the restaurants must have a rating count of more than 50 and the average rating should be greater than 4. Find the restaurants fulfilling the criteria to get the promotional offer.

Should I do a count for ratings and a mean and join both information in one new dataset?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think we only need to calculate the average score of restaurants that meet the requirements (that is, the score exceeds 50), and then create a new dict, {Name: Average Score}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).